# How to Edit Data in Django dropdown HTML form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a form where I am editing single leads data, I submitted data using the Django default admin panel. But now I am editing data on my default form.
So my concern is, if I edit any leads then the default value should be selected in the dropdown which is available in the database, and if I want to change the dropdown value then I can select it from the dropdown list.

Here are my `Models.py` file

```
class Leads(models.Model):
   SOURCE = (
    ('Facebook', 'Facebook'),
    ('Website', 'Website'),
    ('PPC', 'PPC'),
    ('Reference', 'Reference'),
    ('Other Source', 'Other Source')
)
    
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=None)
source = models.CharField(choices=SOURCE, default=2, max_length=100)
```

here are my `urls.py` file

```
path(r'^leads/<int:id>/change',views.leads_edit, name="leads_edit"),
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def leads_edit(request, id):
    leads = Leads.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {'leads':leads}
    template_name = 'file/edit.html'
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

here is my `edit.html` file, where is am trying to edit using the dropdown field...

```
{% for obj in leads.SOURCE %}
    <option value="{{ leads.source }}">{{ obj}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Please check my code and let me know how I can display the selected field from the database, and how I can display the rest other fields in the dropdown list. Because I can change the dropdown fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this, I hope it will help you...

```
{% for id, obj in leads.SOURCE %}
     <option value="{{ id }}"{% if leads.source == id %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ obj }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but pretty sure you might be looking for something like this.

```
SOURCE = (
    ('', '--------'),
    ('Facebook', 'Facebook'),
    ('Website', 'Website'),
    ('PPC', 'PPC'),
    ('Reference', 'Reference'),
    ('Other Source', 'Other Source')
)
```

```
source = models.CharField(choices=SOURCE, default='Website', max_length=100)
```

and defaulting to nothing would be

```
source = models.CharField(choices=SOURCE, default='', max_length=100)
```

where you wrote *default = 2*, I don't think that will work, since the value in your list of choices is a string. If you write them like this instead, then you could potentially default to a numeric value, even while still keeping it a charfield. You could convert to other PositiveInteger Fields as well if you wanted to go that route. The second parameter is just a label to your choice.

```
SOURCE = (
    (0, '--------'),
    (1, 'Facebook'),
    (2, 'Website'),
    (3, 'PPC'),
    (4, 'Reference'),
    (5, 'Other Source')
)
```

but also, wherever your form is actually located, you should probably do something like this in that file in addition to the above. For required, choose one or the other.

```
source = forms.CharField(
    widget = forms.Select(
        choices = SOURCE
    ),
    required = True/False,
    max_length = 100,
)
```

Then in your form class you can try to set the value of the field on the *__init__* per whatever parameters and checks you need to perform. You will have to pass request into the form class when you use the class or just write this instead *def __init__(self, *args, ***kwargs):* instead, depends on if you need request to find your solution and it looks like you might. Passing in request would look something like this *form = LeadsForm(request)* or *form = LeadsForm(request.POST)* and if you need your id *form = LeadsForm(request, some_id)*

```
class LeadsForm(forms.Form):
    source = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.Select(
            choices = SOURCE
        ),
        required = True/False,
        max_length = 100,
    )

    def __init__(self, request, some_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeadsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        {{ your_lead_magic_here... }}

        self.fields['source'].initial = {{ your_calculated_lead_value_here }}
```